# Progress on the paper by Hass and Lagarias on Reidemeister moves needed for unknotting

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Has any progress been made on the findings of 2001 paper by Joel Hass and Jeffrey C. Lagarias? The paper is

- Joel Hass and Jeffrey C. Lagarias, *The number of Reidemeister moves needed for unknotting*, J. Amer. Math. Soc. **14** (2001), 399-428,
  doi:[10.1090/S0894-0347-01-00358-7](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-01-00358-7), arXiv:[math/9807012](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807012)
  .

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Are you asking for a survey of the general area related to the article's theme? If so, that seems overly broad.

Comment: Yes, for example, A Polynomial Upper Bound on Reidemeister Moves by Marc Lackenby in the Annals of Mathematics https://www.jstor.org/stable/24523342

Comment: There is no need to close this question. It's not doing any harm. Worse to worse, this question will remain overly broadly formulated, and thus won't get a (good) answer. But most likely, the OP will edit the question to make it more well-focussed.

Comment: Unfortunately, MathOverflow is crawling with vigilantes.

Comment: See also: [Are there any very hard unknots?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/80679/6094), and [Number of the Reidemeister moves needed to transform one diagram into another one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/190566/6094). Both mention Lackenby's result.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is yes.

Comment: Behind the expensive AMS paywall you can get on MathSciNet [the list](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?refcit=1815217&loc=headline) of the (now 33) published papers quoting this paper. With no paywall, ZBmath [finds](https://zbmath.org/?q=rf%3A1566266) 26 quoting papers. Google Scholar [finds](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cites=262064358851615237&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=fr) more than 100 quotations on the web.

Comment: More recently, Lackenby has announced even more spectacular results: https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/38304